# My program is outputting me 2 random numbers out of 10, the other 8 are normal, but i can't see the problem

Tags: c

My program is supposed to see if the user numbers are the ones they have available (35-44) and then return the numbers (35-44) and the percentage of people who have selected them out of the 10 numbers available.

I've tried everything as if it was normal, but the numbers 35 and 36 are giving me random percentage numbers every time.
The numbers 37-44 are giving me normal percentage numbers so I really don't understand what's happening

The output is supposed to be like that:

```
tamanho 36 – percentual: 20
tamanho 37 – percentual: 10
tamanho 38 – percentual: 0
tamanho 39 – percentual: 0
tamanho 40 – percentual: 0
tamanho 41 – percentual: 0
tamanho 42 – percentual: 10
tamanho 43 – percentual: 0
tamanho 44 – percentual: 30
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
int tamanVeri(int taman,int vTam[]){
  int porc,i;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    if(taman==vTam[i]){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
void showTamanPorc(int vTam[],int vAp[],int vezRepetCSucesso){
  int i;
  float porc;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    porc=((float)vAp[i]/(float)vezRepetCSucesso)*100.0;
    printf("Tamanho:  %i - Porcentagem: %.2f\n",vTam[i],porc);
  }
  
}
int main(void) {
  int vAp[10];
  int vTam[10]={35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44};
  int tamanho,i=0,j=0,k,adicEm;
  printf("Ponha o tamanho do tênis\nEntre 35 e 44\n");
  scanf("%i",&tamanho);
  while(tamanho!=0&&tamanho>0){
    adicEm=tamanVeri(tamanho,vTam);
    if(adicEm!=0){
      vAp[adicEm]++;
    }
    j++;
    printf("Ponha o tamanho do tênis\nEntre 35 e 44\n");
    scanf("%i",&tamanho);
  }
  showTamanPorc(vTam,vAp,j);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your linear search function (`tamanVeri`) has the problem of returning `0` on failure and on successfully finding the integer to be the first element of the array. You should return some non-valid index on failure (e.g., `-1`), and change the comparison used:

```
if (adicEm != -1)
```

`int vAp[10];` is an uninitialized array. The values it contains are *indeterminate* (effectively random). Using an indeterminate value, as in `vAp[adicEm]++;`, invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

Initialize the array to contain all zeroes:

```
int vAp[10] = { 0 };
```